# Crystal Reports reaches job limit despite garbage collection

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a C# application I recently converted into a service. As part of its normal operation, it creates PDF invoices via CR using the following code:

```
foreach (string docentry in proformaDocs)
    using (ReportDocument prodoc = new ReportDocument()) {
        string filename = outputFolder + docentry + ".pdf";
        prodoc.Load(/* .rpt file */);
        prodoc.SetParameterValue(0, docentry);
        prodoc.SetParameterValue(1, 17);
        prodoc.SetDatabaseLogon(/* login data */);
        prodoc.ExportToDisk(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat,
                                filename);
        prodoc.Close();
        prodoc.Dispose();
    }

foreach (string docentry in invoiceDocs)
    using (ReportDocument invdoc = new ReportDocument()) {
        string filename = differentOutputFolder + docentry + ".pdf";
        invdoc.Load(/* different .rpt file */);
        invdoc.SetParameterValue(0, docentry);
        invdoc.SetParameterValue(1, 13);
        invdoc.SetDatabaseLogon(/* login data */);
        invdoc.ExportToDisk(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat,
                                filename);
        invdoc.Close();
        invdoc.Dispose();
    }

GC.Collect();
```

Problem is, after about 3-4 hours of runtime with the above code executing at most every two minutes, the Load() operation hits the processing job limit despite me explicitly disposing the report objects. However, if I leave the service running and launch a non-service instance of the same application, that one executes properly even while the service is still throwing the job limit exception. With the non-service instance having taken care of the processing, the service has nothing to do for the moment - but the instant it does, it throws the error again until I manually stop and restart the service, at which point the error goes away for another 3-4 hours.

How am I hitting the job limit if I'm manually disposing every single report object as soon as I'm done with it and calling garbage collection after each round of processing and disposing? And if the job limit is reached, how can a parallel instance of the same code not be affected by it?

---

UPDATE: I managed to track down the problem and as it turns out, it's not with CR. I take CR's database login credentials from a SAP Company object inside a Database wrapper class stored in a Dictionary, fetched with this:

```
public Company GetSAP(string name) {
    Database db;                    //wrapper class
    SAP.TryGetValue(name, out db);  //fetching from the Dictionary
    return db.SAP;                  //Company object in the wrapper class
}
```

For some reason, calling this freezes the thread, but the Timer launching the service's normal operation naturally doesn't wait for it to complete and launches another thread, which freezes too upon calling this. This keeps up until the number of frozen threads hits the job limit, at which point an exception is thrown by each new thread due to the still frozen threads filling the job limit. I put in a check to not launch a new thread if one is still running and the application froze upon calling the above function.

The getter of the object the `return db.SAP` above calls has literally nothing in it other than a `return`.

Comment: Don't call `GC.Collect` explicitly. It's a code smell and is not needed in 99.(9)% the cases. Also, you don't need to call `Close` and `Dispose` for your `ReportDocument` objects, because this will be done automatically due to the `using` statement.

Comment: Seems to me like LOH fragmentation after loading many report docs. What do you exactly mean by "hit processing job limits"? Is there any kind of exception? I do not know CR well.

Comment: @KonradKokosa
CrystalReportException with the message "Load report failed" and an inner exception of InteropServices.COMException with the message "The maximum report processing jobs limit configured by your system administrator has been reached." There is a default global limit of 75 concurrent jobs, but I'm never processing that many at once and as seen above, they should be garbage-collected long before reaching the limit. Hence why I'm stumped on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, the problem was kinda solved. For some reason, the getters in the COM object I was trying to fetch the login credentials from freeze if accessed from a service but not from a non-service application. Testing this COM-object-stuffed-into-wrapper-class-stuffed-into-Dictionary setup in an IIS application also yielded no freezes. I have no idea why and short of SAP sharing the source code for said COM object, I'm unlikely to ever find out. So I simply declared a few string fields for storing the credentials and cut accessing the COM object out entirely since I didn't need it, only its fields.